# storing data sent back from PHP to ajax in global array

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have successfully built a life expectancy calculator and now want to create a graph. I created an array X that stores values for the age. The program then sends each elements in x to PHP using ajax and php will send back the results.

I want to store the results in a global array Y so that I can create a graph. The problem is the value assignment is done inside success: function{}. The elements will be discarded after that. Below is my code:

```
age();
var yearage = $('input:text[name=ageyr]').val();
value = parseFloat(yearage);
var x = [];
var yVal = [];

var change = [-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5];
var stop = false;
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
{
x[i] = value +change[i];
}

console.log(x);

$('form.ajax').on('submit',function(event){

var that  =$(this), 
url = that.attr('action'),
type = that.attr('method'),
data ={};
var radio_button_value;

if ($("input[name='sex']:checked").length > 0){
gender = $('input:radio[name=sex]:checked').val();
}

that.find ('[name]').each(function(index,value){

var that = $(this),
name = that.attr('name'),
value = that.val();


data[name] = value;
});   

for (var j = 0; j <= 10; ++j){
var information = {

'sex': gender, 
'ageyr' : x[j],
'agemo' :$('input:text[name=agemo]').val(),
'dateyr': $('input:text[name=dateyr]').val(),
'livepercent':$('input:text[name=livepercent]').val(),
'liveyr':$('input:text[name=liveyr]').val(),
'liveage':$('input:text[name=liveage]').val(),
'liveyrschg' :  $('input:hidden[name=liveyrschg]').val() 



}; 

console.log(information);     
$.ajax({

url: url,
type: type,
data: information, 
dataType : "json",    
success: function(results){
var data = results;    
yVal.push( data.lifeexpyr);


console.log(yVal);

}
});



}

 event.preventDefault();

});
```

This is what i got:
 
 ["47.66"]
 ["47.66", "46.62"]
 ["47.66", "46.62", "45.57"]
["47.66", "46.62", "45.57", "44.52"]
["47.66", "46.62", "45.57", "44.52", "43.47"]
 ["47.66", "46.62", "45.57", "44.52", "43.47", "42.42"]
 ["47.66", "46.62", "45.57", "44.52", "43.47", "42.42", "41.38"]
["47.66", "46.62", "45.57", "44.52", "43.47", "42.42", "41.38", "40.33"]
 ["47.66", "46.62", "45.57", "44.52", "43.47", "42.42", "41.38", "40.33", "39.29"]
[["47.66", "46.62", "45.57", "44.52", "43.47", "42.42", "41.38", "40.33", "39.29", "38.25"]
["47.66", "46.62", "45.57", "44.52", "43.47", "42.42", "41.38", "40.33", "39.29", "38.25", "37.21"]

but outside of ajax yVal is empty ! Please help me, I am new to Javascript

Comment: AJAX's first "A" stands for asynchronous your last statement `event.preventDefault` is executed **before** the response...

Comment: Thank you Junius ! I  added this line async : false to  the ajax call and it solved the problem.

Comment: That's a really really... really bad idea! What do you want to achieve?